# How to add a prefix to existing custom fields over MYSQL query?

Tags: custom-field, customization, query

I've got the problem that after a plugin update I can make the `custom fields` on our directory site searchable, but only `custom fields` which get the prefix `booking_` to them.

Now there are some pages (up to thirty already) each with dozens of custom fields. I would like to make a custom field, that is called `testfield` to become `booking_testfield`...
So, all custom fields should get the prefix but it shouldn't break the site.

The theme framework I am working with will create new custom fields on entering a page, but those new fields get the prefix can be managed over the theme framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**important**: backup your database first!

Assuming your table prefix is 'wp_', this query will change the custom field names:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_key = 'booking_testfield' where meta_key = 'testfield';
```

NB: this also assumes that the custom field name is unique to your application, i.e. it isn't used by another post type. If it is possible that another post type is using that field name, then you will need to change the update query to join wp_posts to wp_postmeta and filter on post_type also.

Edit: if you want to **duplicate** the data into new fields, use an `insert` query instead, like this:

```
insert into wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    select post_id, concat('booking_', meta_key), meta_value
    from wp_postmeta
    where meta_key = 'testfield';
```

NB: this will duplicate the data **once**. If you already have some data with the new keys, you'll get multiple values -- add a subquery to eliminate those posts from the insert set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your answers... Only now found the time to try it out. So, I tried it now, but the result was, that the query does some things not, I assumed it would do and others I didnt assume, that would happen.

I used it like this:

Comment: `code`update wp_postmeta set meta_key = 'booking_anzahlbaeder' where meta_key = 'anzahlbaeder';`/code` for example. Becuse this is one of the custom fields, that were generated by the theme framework (premiumpress real estate theme, BTW) and I called the Database Key ID (that is the term the theme takes) anzahlbaeder.  Now, I see, that the value that field was including, like 3 (which in this case means, Number of Bathrooms) was deleted through the query. Which is not optimal, because all the values must stay.

Comment: Which I didnt assume would happen. Secondly, it DID NOT change the Database Key ID in the theme settings.  Thats probably what You already mentioned that those custom fields values could also exist in another table.  
So, I would try to find the table where the theme framework writes those IDs in also.  But the first thing really gives me a problem now. Would You mind helping any further?.  Thanks in advance. Cheers. Andre

Comment: Do you need to preserve the old fields, and duplicate them as new fields with different values? e.g. copy from 'anzahlbaeder' to 'booking_anzahlbaeder'?

Comment: Yes. I think the plugin searchandreplace does the job without deleting the value.  Just hasnt come to my mind to use this one.

Comment: To find here: http://bueltge.de/wp-suchen-und-ersetzen-de-plugin/114
But the right mysql query still is very interesting to me, cause I was surprised that Your query did change the values, I mean set it to blank. I think nobody would really want this as a side effect.